# Excel error in sharepoint

Tags: excel-services

I tried to open this Excel worksheet in Sharepoint and got the following message.

> The Window cannot be opened because it contains the following
>   features that are not supported by Excel in the browser:
>
> - Sheet Protection Would you like to try to open the message in Excel? Learn more about unsupported features.

When I hit "Yes", I then got the second message.

> To open this workbook, your computer must have a version of Microsoft
>   Excel installed and your Web Browser must support opening files
>   directly from Excel in the browser

I tried the solution from below link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/tried-to-open-excel-worksheet-in-sharepoint-but/9b064c48-62d5-45e2-8c89-5c4d0e91d268?page=1 but I am not able to resolve it.

Can you provide me any resolution. I don't have IE-32 bit and have to use 64 bit only which is giving error.

Comment: The solution is in the error message itself.
You say you have 64-bit IE, but his and Excel, his version is compatible with your browser?
Read the message and you'll see it's a problem of compatibility software.

Comment: what step i need to follow to remove error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the spreadsheet uses the "Spreadsheet and database integration" features of Excel, it will not work in IE 64bit, this is due to this module not being compatible with the 64-bit browser versions of IE.

More information about Browser support and limitations for SharePoint 2010 here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: As I remarked, the solution is in the error message itself, incompatible software

Comment: I am using IE8 32 bit but still getting same error. sometime it work but sometime it doesnot. Is there any permanent solution for the same.